# Прошу помочь новичку в JS

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JS самостоятельно, столкнулся с примером по которому нет понимания может знающий человек подскажет.

```
function test() {
    let a = 0;
    return function newTest() {
         return ++a;
    }; 
}
let znach = test();
console.log(znach())
```

Вопрос такой почему, код выше работает нормально и печатет значение 1. А код ниже не работает и выдает значение [Function: newTest], хотя как по мне и в первом и во втором случае вызов функции test равнозначный.

```
function test() {
   let a = 0;
   return function newTest() {
        return ++a;
   }; 
}
console.log(test())
```

Comment: В первом случае есть два вызова функции `test()` и `znach()`, а во втором случае только один `test()`. Если вы добавите второй вызов, написав `test()()`, то станет хорошо

Comment: Ну и наоборот, если в первом случае убрать второй вызов функции, написав `console.log(znach)`, то станет аналогично второму случаю

Comment: Чуть расширю и так понятный ответ andreymal, для тех у кого остался вопрос "Что присходит?")
Во внешней функции создается переменная и возвращается другая функция, увеличивающая переменную на 1.
В первом случае, создаётся переменная, которой присваивается результат внешней функции, т.е увеличивающая функция, а потом уже она и отдаёт результат в console.
Во втором случае же, в консоль идёт результат внешней функции, т.е "увеличивающая" функция и по этому мы получаем такой вывод.